# Array changing value logic in histogram calculation

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, image-processing

I am following a course on openclassroom about basic image processing and it mainly uses OpenCV.  There is something I don't quite understand about a piece of code that is supposed to make a histogram displaying the intensity of `gray` in the picture.

At some point we make a vector and the vector's values change for no reason I can understand at the moment.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# we upload the picture in a matrix
image = cv.imread("Lenna.png")

# change it to gray levels in this process
b,v,r = cv.split(image)         
y = 0.299*r + 0.587*v + 0.114*b 
y = y.astype(np.uint8)          

#Ou histogram vectors
hist = np.zeros(256, int)
print(hist[y[1,10]])
# hist is obviously zero here and so is hist[y[i,j] for every
# i and j in the range below

for i in range(0,image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,image.shape[1]):

        # When I check hist values I see that it has changed
        # And I don't know why it changed 
        print(hist[y[1,10]])
        hist[y[i,j]] = hist[y[i,j]] + 1

#print(hist)
#plt.plot(hist)
#plt.show()
```

The code works perfectly, I just want to understand what is happening to my vector `hist`

Comment: What the code snippet is intending to do is to calculate the frequency of various gray scale pixel values. You could have used a `dict` for this as well where key of the `dict` would be the intensity and value would be the frequency count of that intensity. Or you could use a fixed array of size 256(because the range of gray scale pixels is 0-255). The course is using the latter technique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite your for loop like this for readability:

```
for i in range(0,image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,image.shape[1]):
        pixel_value = y[i,j]
        hist[pixel_value] += 1
```

This makes it clearer that the second line of the for loop is modifying a value int the `hist` array, and also what that value represents (a count of how many times we've seen that pixel value).

Comment: I finally understand how this works, thank you so muuuch

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a histogram counts up how many times you see an intensity in an image.  The basics are to iterate over each pixel, see what its value is then we record that we have seen this pixel and increase the count.

Start with a simple example.  Suppose I have an image that contains:

```
0  1  2
2  2  3
4  5  1
```

A histogram counts up how many times we see a particular value.  In this case, our histogram would look like a 6 element array such that each element tells you how many times we see that element.

Therefore:

```
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 
 [1 2 3 1 1 1]
```

I've placed the intensity value at the top of the array for illustration.  For each value / intensity in the histogram, we see how many times we have seen that number in the entire image.  The same logic is applied with the above code snippet.  We observe the intensity, then increase the count of seeing this by 1.  That's what `hist[y[i,j]] = hist[y[i,j]] + 1` is doing.  Access the intensity at location `y[i,j]`, then increase the count for this intensity by 1.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, your `image` is an array of size `width x height x No. color channels`. "Lenna" images are mostly square, three-channel ("color") images, so let's say your `image` has a size of `200 x 200 x 3`.

Afterwards, you do a manual color-to-grayscale conversion using a specific [luma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)) formula. In the end, your `y` then is a grayscale image (or an array) of size `width x height` with values between `0` and `255`.

Now, for  specific "image coordinates" like `i = 5` and `j = 6`, you can access the pixel/intensity value in `y` like this: `y[i,j]`. Let's say, the value at that position is `124`.

Your `hist` vector has `256` elements, that can be accessed by indices from `0` to `255`, which perfectly fits our above pixel/intensity values. And, all entries of `y` are `0` in the beginning.

Now, we're iterating through the whole image:

```py
for i in range(0, image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, image.shape[1]):
```

`i` goes from `0` to `199`. And for each `i`, `j` also goes from `0` to `199`, covering all pixels in our image.

Inside the loop, we get the pixel/intensity value at position `(i,j)` as shown above: `y[i,j]`. Let's say it's `124`. We then access the corresponding entry in `hist`, i.e. `hist[y[i,j]]` is the same as `hist[124]`.

Finally, we increment the corresponding entry in `hist` by `1`, so before `hist[124]` was `0`, and now `hist[124]` becomes `1`.

In the end, you count how often each pixel/intensity value appears in your image `y`. So, `hist[124]` might be `1452`, when the whole routine is done.

Hope that helps!